# ReactJS and disable/enable selected field

Tags: reactjs, forms, input

I'm trying to have disabled/enabled selected input field for edits. So far I have it done for all fields at once as

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { disabled: true }
}
handleEdit() {
    this.setState( {disabled: !this.state.disabled} )
}

render(){
    return(
        <div className="col-md-3"><label>First Name</label></div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
        <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control react-form-input"
            id="fname"
            name="fname"
            disabled={(this.state.disabled)? "disabled" : ""}
        />
        <i className="fas fa-edit" onClick = {this.handleEdit.bind(this)}></i>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-3"><label>Last Name</label></div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
        <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control react-form-input"
            id="lname"
            name="lname"
            disabled={(this.state.disabled)? "disabled" : ""}
        />
        <i className="fas fa-edit" onClick = {this.handleEdit.bind(this)}></i>
        </div>
       )}
```

but then I want to edit only selected field based on the element ID. I have tried to switch it to handle as an `event.target.id` but that wasn't working at all.

Any tips on that matter?

Comment: The better way is to move your input and edit button into separate component which will has separate state.

Comment: @demkovych I was thinking about it at the beginning but  I was looking on that at the form level component rather than only selected field. I have got stuck with the parent component as I have multiple forms to submit with one submit button only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the editable states of each input in an object:

```
state = {
  editable: {}
};

handleEdit = id => {
  this.setState(({ editable }) => ({
    editable: { ...editable, [id]: !editable[id] }
  }));
};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="col-md-3">
        <label>First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control react-form-input"
          id="fname"
          name="fname"
          disabled={!this.state.editable.fname}
        />
        <i className="fa fa-edit" onClick={() => this.handleEdit("fname")} />
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-3">
        <label>Last Name</label>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control react-form-input"
          id="lname"
          name="lname"
          disabled={!this.state.editable.lname}
        />
        <i className="fa fa-edit" onClick={() => this.handleEdit("lname")} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working Example:

[image: Edit exciting-nobel-b2k8p]

Comment: Well. I think code is invalid. I will set state at first click as empty not what was provided `onClick` then the state is not updated on another `onClick` for the same element `id`

Comment: @JackTheKnife I forgot the square brackets around `id` in `handleEdit`. It should be working now. Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-nobel-b2k8p

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component that encapsulates the editing state

```
function EditableField(props) {
  const [editing, setEditing] = React.useState(false);

  function toggleEditing() {
    setEditing(currentState => !currentState);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label>{props.label}</label>
      <input 
        value={props.value} 
        onChange={props.onChange}
        disabled={props.disabled || !editing}
      />
      <button onClick={toggleEditing}>
        {editing ? 'Save' : 'Edit'}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Demo

```js
function EditableField(props) {
  const [editing, setEditing] = React.useState(false);
  
  function toggleEditing() {
    setEditing(currentState => !currentState);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{props.label}</label>
      <input 
        value={props.value} 
        onChange={props.onChange}
        disabled={props.disabled || !editing}
      />
      <button onClick={toggleEditing}>
        {editing ? 'Save' : 'Edit'}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

EditableField.defaultProps = {
  editing: false,
  disabled: false
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <EditableField label="FirstName"/>
      <EditableField label="LastName"/>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That solution is good when the form submitting is done on edit button disable but not when submit whole (multiple forms) at once.

Comment: by form you mean the `<form>` element or the inputs?

Comment: Yeah - I have multiple `<form>` components in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I have came up with working solution for my code based on @trixn suggestion:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { }
}
handleEdit(id) {
        let setEdit = this.state[id];
        this.setState( {[id]: !setEdit});
}

render(){
    return(
        <div className="col-md-3"><label>First Name</label></div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
        <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control react-form-input"
            id="fname"
            name="fname"
            disabled={!this.state.fname}
        />
        <i className="fas fa-edit" onClick = {() => this.handleEdit('fname')}></i>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-3"><label>Last Name</label></div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
        <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control react-form-input"
            id="lname"
            name="lname"
            disabled={!this.state.lname}
        />
        <i className="fas fa-edit" onClick = {() => this.handleEdit('lname')}></i>
        </div>
       )}
```